# Como utilizar http.get() no Flutter WEB?

Tags: aplicação-web, flutter, dart

Estou tentando rodar um projeto Mobile do Flutter em WEB.

Existe uma parte que fazemos uma requisição *http* num endpoint pra pegar uns dados em JSON que é utilizado o seguinte trecho:

```
final response = await http.get("http://localhost:4141/apicardapio.php?testeconexao=OK");
```

No Mobile funciona corretamente, porém no projeto compilado em WEB está dando o seguinte Exception:

> ```
> message = "XMLHttpRequest error".
>
> uri = {_SimpleUri} http://localhost:4141/apicardapio.php?testeconexao=OK
> _fragmentStart = 56
> _hashCodeCache = null
> _hostStart = 7
> _pathStart = 24
> _portStart = 19
> _queryStart = 40
> _schemeCache = "http"
> _schemeEnd = 4
> _uri = "http://localhost:4141/apicardapio.php?testeconexao=OK"
> ```

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

Answer (score -1):

Para resolver a situação acima, fiz duas coisas:

1. Publiquei a API em um servidor para acessar através de DNS ao invés de localhost.
2. Inseri o header abaixo no arquivo (API em PHP) que faz a consulta acima:

   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");